# How do I disassociate my Google account from Google Friend Connect?

Tags: google-plus

I have a [Google Friend Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Friend_Connect) account and would like to leave it behind. How do I do that?

Is it related to, or is there any difference, between Google Friend Connect and [Google+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%2B)?

What is Google Friend Connect even for?

Comment: Did you want to leave Google Friend Connect or are you asking about embedding your G+ circles? Two very different questions

Comment: @Eight Days of Malaise, I want to leave Google Friend Connect. Maybe I put them all here because I realised I left so many new questions here today. I'll update this question if it's misleading. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Made an update to make it pointedly about Friend Connect since you'll get better answers when your question is focussed. If you're still asking about embedding G+, it's better if you asked a new question

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise, howaa thanks a lot for your better explanation of my question, that was what I wanted to say!! Thanks for your update!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Friend Connect is a service made available to web site owners to easily create a community around a web site. There does not appear to be a way to abandon Google Friend Connect all at once, but you can do it a site at a time.

To see the list of sites you have joined using Google Friend Connect, go to the [**Sites I've Joined**](http://www.google.com/friendconnect/user/overview) page.

To leave a site in the list, click the **Settings** link next to the site, then click **Stop following this site**.

Comment: I don't have any sites on Sites I've joined since I've never been interested in joining any sites. What I want is not how to leave or unjoin a site that I joined using Google Friend Connect. But, how do I leave Google Friend Connect, in another word, **how do I disassociate my Google account from Google Friend Connect?** I've updated my question. Anyhow, thanks for enlightenment I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have a Friend Connect section on your [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/)?

Comment: No, I don't have that on my google dashboard.

Comment: Then it appears you have removed any Friend Connect information from your Google account. That's what you wanted, right?